# AVPlayerController in UIView is blank on restarting the app

Tags: swift, xcode, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am working on a messaging app. When I select a video from the gallery and send in the message it works fine. But when I close/kill the app and reopen the app, it shows me a blank view with video player controls like a full-screen play button, etc.

The strange thing is when I send another video in chat the previous blank video starts appearing. If I don't kill the after sending the video and go back to the previous screen and come back again to the chat screen video works fine. The only problem is when I kill the app.

Table View Cell Code

```
var player: AVPlayer? = nil
var url: URL?
var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer? = nil
var playerViewController : AVPlayerViewController? = nil
var viewModel: SenderVideoTableViewCellViewModel! {
    didSet {
        bind()
    }
}
func bind() {
 guard let url = URL(string: self.viewModel.message) else { return }
            let urlPath = url //Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sampleVideo", withExtension: "mp4")
            self.player = AVPlayer(url: urlPath)
     
            
            self.playerViewController?.player?.pause()
            self.playerViewController?.player = nil
            self.playerViewController = nil
            self.playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
            self.playerViewController?.player = self.player
            
            
            if let playerViewController = self.playerViewController {
                self.videoContainerView.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
            }
            
            self.playerViewController?.view.frame.size.height = self.videoContainerView.frame.size.height
            self.playerViewController?.view.frame.size.width = self.videoContainerView.frame.size.width
            self.playerViewController?.view.frame = self.videoContainerView.bounds

}


 func stopVideo() {
    player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil) 
    player?.pause()
}
```

Any help regarding this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: It seems like the video URL is configured in your `self.viewModel.message` - how is this getting set ?

Comment: yes I have a viewModel in which I have a Model which I get it from Realm Database. But the issue is not with ``self.vewModel.message`` as I checked the file path it's correct. I also checked the path after sending another video the first video path is same as saved in Realm database

Comment: When do you launch the AVPlayerViewController ? Is it on app launch in `didLoad` etc ? Is it on a tap of the button ? Also how is your UI set up to display the AVPlayerViewController ?

Comment: My cell code is in my Custom TableViewCell. I am configuring my viewModel in `cellForRowAt indexPath` like this. `cell.viewModel = CustomCellModel(...)` this will call the bind function.